# Can we write the action for Home button in iphone

Tags: iphone, cydia

I am going to develop an application which will be posted in cydia. My requirement is after unlocking the iphone when the user clicks the home button then my application need to be popedup(run) ..

is it possible to do this? 
if yes how?

Comment: but apple will reject on using home button action

Comment: Thanx narayanan but i am not going to submit this app in app store . i will submit it in cydia

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any extra code by changing the settings in Activator. The app doesn't need to be in Cydia, either.

1. Confirm you have Activator installed from Cydia.
2. Go to the Settings app, followed by Activator.
3. Choose which environment you want the action to run in: Anywhere, Home Screen, in an app or Lock Screen.
4. Scroll down to “Home button” and tap the action you want.
5. Scroll down again, until you see the app you want. Tap it and confirm there is a check mark next to it.

Now your app will start every time the action occurs. If you want this to be automatically set when your app is installed, however, you'll need to include the libactivator header in your code and use its API to set the action. Because the header isn't included with iOS, you'll need to make the app for Cydia.